# Cyclotomic Polynomials conceptual question

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering why do we always get an integer coefficient for each variable and constant everytime we compute $\phi_n$ ?

Comment: Do you mean the coefficients of the cyclotomic pol. over the rationals (in fact, over the integers), or about its values? If it is the first then that's a very nice and non-trivial theorem, and if it is the second then it isn't true...

Comment: http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/18.pdf;
http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/cyp.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive $n$-th roots of unity are algebraic integers.
Hence the coefficients of $\Phi_n$ are algebraic integers.
Since they are rational numbers, they are rational integers because $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed in $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the following formula and induction on n.

$\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X) = X^n - 1$

Let $g(X) = \prod_{d\mid n, d ＜ n}\Phi_d(X)$.
By the induction hypothesis $g(X) ∈ \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and it is monic.
Hence $\Phi_n(X) = (X^n - 1)/g(X) ∈ \mathbb{Z}[X]$

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways we can define the Cyclotomic polynomials, for example there are already three in the introduction of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) wikipedia page.

Of those three, two make the integer coefficients part of the definition. For the other definition they list: $$\Phi_n(X) =\prod_\stackrel{1\le k\le n-1}{\gcd(k,n)=1}(X-e^{2i\pi\frac{k}{n}})$$

two options I can see are to either prove the formula Makoto used in his answer, or to show that the primitive roots of unity are a Galois conjugate family in the appropriate field extension, and thus the product on the right hand side is their minimal polynomial.